# How can I make wifi access point on Banana pro? P

Tags: banana-pi

I have installed [bananian](https://www.bananian.org) OS on Banana pro. Now I want to make wifi access point on banana pro.

Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the WiFi Driver

Run the following command to load the WiFi driver at boot time.

```
root@bananapi ~ # nano /etc/modules
# add the wifi driver
ap6210 op_mode=2
```

Adding Internet Access

While your WiFi users can connect to your BananaPro, they can’t do much else except to run apps on the BananaPro. Assuming you have your eth0 port connected to a network that has internet access, you can give them access to the Internet. All it requires is enabling IPv4 forwarding to allow traffic to pass between the eth0 and wlan0 ports.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

To make this permanent, edit the /etc/sysctl file and un-comment the line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

[Reference](http://www.myhsd.net/?p=221#more-221) for adding connection

Comment: thanks a lot. I can see now network. I was missing one or two step. Thanks again